# How do I compare a string and an integer in Python?

Tags: python, string, input, int

I am quite a newbie in Python.
I wrote this and got this error when i typed a letter in the input:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() >= int()
```

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
user_input = input('How old are you?: ')
if user_input >= 18:
   print('You are an adult')
elif user_input < 18:
     print('You are quite young')
elif user_input == str():
     print ('That is not a number')
```

Comment: it should be `user_input = int(input('How old are you?: '))`

Comment: Thanks but this time it says: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

Comment: @Keretto Enter a valid number when prompted.

Comment: `elif user_input == str()` is _not_ how you say "if `user_input` can't be parsed as some kind of number." Please read the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 8):

You should do:

```
user_input = int(input('How old are you?: '))
```

so as you explicitly cast your input as int, it will always try to convert the input into an integer, and will raise a **ValueError** when you enter a string that can't be converted to an int. To handle those cases, do:

```
except ValueError:
    print('That is not a number')
```

So, the full solution might be like below:

```
try:
    user_input = int(input('How old are you?: '))
except ValueError:
    print('That is not a number')
else:
    if user_input >= 18:
        print('You are an adult')
    else:
        print('You are quite young')
```

Comment: Thanks everyone I understand what you mean but it is saying invalid syntax now (except ValueError:)

Answer (score 1):

`user_input` is a `str`, you're comparing it to an `int`. Python does not know how to do that. You will need to convert one of them to the other type to get a proper comparison.

For example, you can convert a string to an integer with the `int()` function:

```
user_input = int(input('How old are you?: '))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = input('How old are you?: ')
try:
    age = int(user_input)
except ValueError:
    print('Please use an integer for age')
    continue          # assuming you have this is an input loop
if user_input < 18:
     print('You are quite young')
```